# secure imap connection in java

Tags: java, ssl, imap

I am trying to connect to our imap server listening on port 993 using a java program I found at :

http://harikrishnan83.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/access-gmail-with-imap-using-java-mail-api/

I am running this program on from Ubuntu.
   However, I am getting below exception for this :

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:479)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at org.myorg.IMAP.main(IMAP.java:40)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:523)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:355)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:753)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.read0(ResponseInputStream.java:81)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:67)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:83)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:48)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:122)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:230)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:91)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:87)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:446)
    ... 3 more
```

At the end of this post they have suggested :
Looks like you have to add imap server’s certificate to your trusted cert store

1. Download imap server’s certificate
2. Locate your cacerts file
3. Use keytool to import the certificate to your cacerts file

However, I am not able to understand how to carry out these steps for an IMAP server running on Windows machine.

Could anybody pl. help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, you are problably not connecting to a SSL encrypted port, but to a plaintext port. Please update your question with your actual configuration (host, port, protocol).

If you were missing the certificate, you would get a totally different error message.

Comment: configuration is as follows :          Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.put("mail.imaps.host", "1.2.3.4");   
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");   
        props.put("mail.imaps.port", 993);   
        props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", 993);   
        props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

Comment: @GregS There are two ways: connecting plaintext IMAP (port 143) and issuing the STARTTLS, or connecting through SSL to port 993 (which is the SSL encrypted IMAP port). They are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you show what's the solution here?